# How I can exclusively use socket port in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, server

I am looking for a method to prevent other scripts to reuse tcp port I am using for listening.

```
$socket = stream_socket_server('tcp://0.0.0.0:8196', $errcode, $errtxt);
```

This line will create a server socket which means nobody can use 8196 port. However I can open more sockets or the same port. Why? How I can prevent this?

Comment: @Dagon No, I don't want to stop PHP script. I need to prevent other scripts (or the same script executed twice) be capable to create another socket on this port. (Let it return false instead)

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Once the socket is opened, another attempt from a another instance of the same script would fail with `PHP Warning:  stream_socket_server(): unable to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:8196 (Address already in use)`

Comment: @hek2mgl May you show your code please?

Comment: I've just put your single line of code plus a `sleep(100);` into a script called `server.php` and executed it using `php -ddisplay_errors=1 server.php` in two separate terminals.

Comment: I can sortof repro this. Opening multiple sockets from the same instance is possible:

 `<?php

 var_dump($s1 = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:7777", $errno, $errstr));
 var_dump($s2 = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:7777", $errno, $errstr));`